# How to regenerate Action Points?

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization

What are some commonly used ways to regenerate action points? Off the top of my head, I know of

- Symbol of Victory's Property
- Sidhe Lord's U2, Sidhe Bargain
- Ghost of the Past's U10, Time Jaunt

Are there any others that are commonly used in builds?

Answer (score 3):

#### There aren't any commonly-used ways of regenerating action points.

The thing to remember about action points is that they're doubly limited. You start the day with one, then you get one more per milestone; that effectively limits you to a rate of one action point per two fights. But even if you had infinite action points, you could only double that rate, because once you use an action point you can't use another one until you've taken a short rest, i.e. once per fight.

While there are, as mentioned, a few different ways to regain expended action points, there are *very* few ways to bypass the limit on action points per encounter. Off the top of my head only the level 30 capstone feature of the Warmaster epic destiny (from Martial Power 1) allows you to do so.

That secondary limit, and the difficulty of bypassing it, has meant that action points have historically not featured prominently in optimization (with 1 caveat, see below). It's simply not worth it to invest resources in being able to jump through hoops to get an action point every encounter instead of every other encounter, when most optimization already focuses on being able to do powerful things at-will, or at least multiple times per encounter. Crit-fishing avengers will often pick up a Symbol of Victory, but that's about it.

---

The exception to this is one of the most broken combos ever in 4e: the Apocalypse Twins. I would have to go digging to find the details, but it combined the following:

1. A ranger with the Horizon Walker paragon path (notable feature: when you spend an action point to take a move action, you get the action point back)
2. A warlord with the Warmaster epic destiny (notable feature: no limit on action points per encounter)
3. One of the above having some way to let an ally take a move action in their place or spend an action point in their place
4. A feat or feature that allowed you to use movement to enter foes' spaces and push them away
5. A feat or item that deals damage to foes whenever you push them

The result is a pair that can spend an infinite number of move actions per turn, and can use move actions to deal damage. Basically, in a single round this pair can explore the entirety of whatever plane they're in and kill every enemy they find by repeatedly shoving them.

Naturally this combination got nerfed by WotC in a hurry, so if you use the errata then it's not an option (Horizon Walker was nerfed to give you a bonus move action when you spent an action point for an extra action). And even if you don't use the errata, it still requires two level 30 characters to pull off and will result in your DM bludgeoning you to death with his or her dice bag.

Comment: Hrm, okay then. I guess I was just mainly wondering since it seemed like a lot of the X-Switch builds seemed to use action points for Flame of Hope or Warchanter's 11th level features, so maybe I thought AP-optimization was more common than it actually is.

Comment: @T.Smit The Switch builds have AP boosts because 1) it's basically built into warlords, and 2) it enhances alpha striking (which is what the Switch builds are all about). But even in a 4 person party you can have 2 players action point per fight, which tends to be sufficient for an alpha strike, and larger parties can obviously use APs more often than that.

Comment: The War Chanter PP (restricted to Valorous Bards) lets you use up to 2 APs in an encounter starting at level 16. Not unlimited, but still doubled. They also give massive boosts to the party when you use an AP.